# Find the index of a value/char without using any list methods

Tags: python, list, indexing

```
def find(my_list, value):
    find = -1
    for i in range(length(my_list)):
        if my_list[i] == value:
            find += 1     
    return find

def length(my_list):
    list_length = 0
    for char in my_list:
        list_length += 1
    return list_length

str_list1 = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']

print("\nfind Test")

print(list_function.find(str_list1, 'g'))

print(list_function.find(str_list1, 'z'))
```

The output is 0 and -1, while we are looking for 3 and -1.

Need to create it without using built-in methods.

Comment: This question is extremely vague and doesn't provide any real info for us to help with... What are the contents of my_list, or of value? Why are you expecting 3 and -1 returned? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: print("\nfind Test")
print(list_function.find(str_list1, 'g'))
print(list_function.find(str_list1, 'z'))

Comment: still unclear what is str_list1?

Comment: str_list1 = ['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g']

Comment: values we are checking are "g" and "z"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
def find(my_list, value):
    for index, element in enumerate(my_list):
        if element == value:
            return index
    return -1

print(find(['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g'], 'g'))
# 3

print(find(['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g'], 'z'))
# -1
```

If you need no built-ins to be used, this is one way:

```
def find(my_list, value):
    index = 0
    for element in my_list:
        if element == value:
            return index
        index += 1
    return -1

print(find(['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g'], 'g'))
# 3

print(find(['r', 'i', 'n', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'g'], 'z'))
# -1
```

Comment: can it be done with length command, because I can't use any built-in method? Please help me

Comment: But you used `range`. It's also built-in. There is no `length` command. Do you mean `len(list)` but that again a list function. :/

Comment: using a predefined function called length.